# Gravitational pull vs. acceleration due to gravity

Tags: gravity, acceleration

It might seem obvious but i can't imagine how is gravitational pull is different from acceleration due to gravity?

Answer (score 6):

Gravitational pull is the cause - the force. Acceleration is the consequence of this cause, assuming that the gravitational force is not cancelled by another force.

Answer (score 4):

The term "gravitational pull" is probably meant to convey *force*, which is related to but distinct from acceleration.

Under a common assumption of constant mass (which may be false in general, e.g. , a rocket ) , $F = ma$ by Newton's second law , so you don't lose much except conceptual precision in very simple situations... but such conceptual difference can become rather important.

Answer (score 0):

Typically "gravitational force" is defined as 
$$
F = G\frac{Mm}{r^2}
$$
Dividing both sides by $m$ we get
$$
\frac{F}{m} = G\frac{M}{r^2}
$$
$\frac{F}{m}$ is acceleration and a gravitational field will accelerate any "free to fall" object within that field at the acceleration of that field irrespective of the mass of the object.  Gravitation is not a force but an acceleration